# AWS Lambda function filtering based on tags

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I am trying to filter ec2 instances based on their tag names.It doesn't work properly. I am looking for any available ec2 instances with these tags on:

```
    var params = {
      DryRun: false,
      Filters: [
            {
                Name: "tag:Name",
                Values: ["2test-dev-gh"],
            },
            {
                Name: "tag:Enviro",
                Values: ["devInstanceStatus"],
            },
            {
              Key: "tag:Proj",
              Value: ["dev-2test"],
          },
          {
              Key: "tag:testServers",
              Value: ["peekhours"]
          }
          
          ]
    };
```

This filter works when I use first tag and comment out others tags but when I try all the tags together, it gives me following error.

```
{
  "errorType": "MultipleValidationErrors",
  "errorMessage": "There were 4 validation errors:\n* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'Key' found in params.Filters[2]\n* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'Value' found in params.Filters[2]\n* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'Key' found in params.Filters[3]\n* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'Value' found in params.Filters[3]",
  "trace": [
    "MultipleValidationErrors: There were 4 validation errors:",
    "* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'Key' found in params.Filters[2]",
    "* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'Value' found in params.Filters[2]",
    "* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'Key' found in params.Filters[3]",
    "* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'Value' found in params.Filters[3]",
    "    at ParamValidator.validate (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:40:28)",
    "    at Request.VALIDATE_PARAMETERS (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/event_listeners.js:126:42)",
    "    at Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)",
    "    at callNextListener (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:96:12)",
    "    at /var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/event_listeners.js:86:9",
    "    at finish (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/config.js:379:7)",
    "    at /var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/config.js:397:9",
    "    at EnvironmentCredentials.get (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/credentials.js:127:7)",
    "    at getAsyncCredentials (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/config.js:391:24)",
    "    at Config.getCredentials (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/config.js:411:9)"
  ]
}
```

This is my rest of code.

```
exports.handler = async function(event) {
  const promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    const ec2 = new AWS.EC2();
    

    ec2.describeInstances(params, function(err, data) {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
    } else {
        resolve(data);
    }    
}) 
});

    return promise;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your params should match below structure, try replacing params with this.

```
   var params = {
      DryRun: false,
      Filters: [
            {
                Name: "tag:Name",
                Values: ["2test-dev-gh"],
            },
            {
                Name: "tag:Enviro",
                Values: ["devInstanceStatus"],
            },
            {
                Name: "tag:Proj",
                Values: ["dev-2test"],
            },
            {
                Name: "tag:testServers",
                Values: ["peekhours"]
            }
          
          ]
    };
```

The cause was using `Key` rather than `Name` and `Value` rather than `Values`.